# CSS - position multiple background images with tiles

Tags: css

I've created some tiles and want to position them within one . My problem starts already in the header line.
The red parts are "header-left.png" and "header-right.png" the violet part is a repeating tile "header-center.png".

What I already have:

```
.test {
width: 800px;
height: 200px;
border: dashed 1px #006597;
background-image: url('../images/standard/header-left.gif'), 
    url('../images/standard/header-center.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
}
```

**But how can I tell the second background, to start after 50px so it starts after the header-left.gif? And how can I position the third background so it is aligned to the right?**

This is what I get now:
[image: example1]

This is my goal:
[image: example2]
red: header-left
violet: repeating header-center
black: header-right
green: repeating background
blue: footer-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
<container>
  <header>
    <div class="red">
    <div class="purple">
    <div class="black">
  </header>
  <div class="green">
...
```

CSS

```
.header{
  width: 800px;
}

.red{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}

.purple{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 650px;
}

.black{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

And add your current background info

Comment: This works only if I have fixed width in my elements. But the center element is variable.

Comment: Try This:  http://jsfiddle.net/L2Yg5/ Make sure the black div before the purple one in the html

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your header within a container and have 3 separate elements that are floated next to each other:

```
#headerLeft{/*Custom Styles*/}
#headerCenter{/*Custom Styles*/}
#headerRight{/*Custom Styles*/}
```

Have a body container and a footer container.

**[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Q6Lnw/181/)**

You can swap out the background-color styles with your images and it should be what you're looking for.

Comment: This works only if I have fixed width in my elements. But the center element is variable.

Comment: You have a fixed width of 800px in your .test example. And you're using two images to cap the center repeating section correct?

Answer (score 0):

divide the header in three div and then load the background for the each header divs